# loadview getting called infinite times

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have two ViewControllers in my app `ViewController1.m` and `ViewController2.m`.

In `AppDelegate` I am having this code.

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

// Override point for customization after application launch.
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    self.viewController = [[ViewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
}
else
{
    self.viewController = [[ViewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
}


self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

In ViewController1.m I have added a button and on button click I am displaying another view controller `ViewController2.m` like this:

```
ViewController2 * obj = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

[self.view addSubview:obj.view];
```

In the `loadView` of ViewController2.m I am adding another button like this

```
NSLog(@"\n Load view called");

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(onButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[button setTitle:@"Back to previous view" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);

[self.view addSubview:button];
```

When I run my app, on clicking the button present in ViewController1.m the app hangs and `loadView` of ViewController2.m starts getting called infinitely.

I dont know the reasin behind this problem, I just wanted to load another ViewController on a button click and I am not using any Navigation Controller.

Can someone point out the reason behind this issue?

Comment: Just see the method stack trace and you can easily find which method or statement is calling loadview again and again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do this in `loadView`. Instead move your code to `viewDidLoad`. The problem is you're accessing `self.view` within `loadView`, which basically calls `loadView` since the initial call to `loadView` never returned.

Sorry for the tongue twister... `loadView` is called automatically when the view hasn't yet been instantiated. Only when it returns is the view initialization complete. If it hasn't return and you try to access the `view` property, it'll call it again. And in your case, it's recursive because you are still in the `loadView` method.

From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> The view controller calls this method when its view property is requested but is currently nil. This method loads or creates a view and assigns it to the view property.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `initWithNibName` do not oveeride `loadView`. Its a wrong design. If you do not want to use `viewDidLoad` and want to something in initialize phase, then override this method,

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // write your init code here.
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The exclusive job of `loadView` is to set the viewControllers view property. That could be something like

`self.view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];`

Imagine that the getter of your view property looks something like this:

```
 if(!_view)
     [self loadView];

  return _view;
```

This means that if you use self.view before setting the view (like in loadView), loadView will be called over and over again. My advice is typically to avoid overriding loadView and instead create a simple `configureView` method that is called from both `awakeFromNib` and `initWithNib...` so the view can be created properly either from a storyboard or nib or instantiated by code.